# Gesture to dismiss `.sheet` on Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

The behavior I am getting when using the `.sheet` modifier on SwiftUI is that the *displayed sheet cannot be dismissed using swipe down gesture on a Mac (Catalyst)* which is expected because ... Mac doesn't come with a touchscreen. This leads to having to add many `#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) ... #endif` to add a button to close the sheet:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show dialog") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            VStack {
                Text("Dialog").font(.title)
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
                Button("Close", action: { showSheet = false })
#endif
                Spacer()
            }.padding(10)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: I choose a close button and keyboardShortcut.

Comment: and do not hesitate to use #if.

Comment: keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction) in sheet NOT work only if parent view is NavagationStack.

Comment: There's no way to avoid using conditionals, at least not given the state of MacCatalyst as of early 2024.  Luckily, there's at least a consistent way to have your injected control dismiss the modal dialog: [the dismiss property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss/).  This always works, even for sheets with no access to the binding that controls their appearance.